# How to change the left arrow icon in actionBar on Titanium Appcelerator?

Tags: android-actionbar, titanium, appcelerator

I would change the left arrow icon in actionBar in Titanium Appcelerator, the icon visible if the property "displayHomeAsUp" is true. I tried to search on google but no solutions I found, someone can help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe with this module https://github.com/ricardoalcocer/actionbarextras, but I'm not sure if it is possible

Answer (score 0):

That's a Android system-provided feature that you cannot change.